# Submit form in MVC using HTML

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, forms, post

I have web application that is using MVC5 with C#. In this app, I have a form with one dropdownlist and a submit button that looks like the following:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="@Url.Action("AssignTemplate", "TemplateMapper")" method="post">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Template:</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select id="template">
                @foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> entry in Model.templates)
                {
                    <option value="@entry.Key">@entry.Value</option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Assign" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("AssignTemplate", "TemplateMapper")'" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

My objective here, without using Razor Html Helper syntax, is to send a post request to the server containing the information selected in the dropdownlist.

To achieve this, I have the following Controller code:

```
public class TemplateMapperController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AssignTemplate(int templateId)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

However, when I press the submit button, I get a 404, not found, even though the method exists and I state in the form that it should be a `post` request.

What am I missing? How can my controller then access the information on the dropdownlist?

Comment: Your AssignTemplate method should accept a Model which contains the data in the POST, however I don't think that's the issue as it wouldn't result in a 404. Can you check what's being posted using Chrome inspector?

Comment: if you look at the source what does the action attribute say it will submit too? the 404 will relate to the location, it is likely that the path is incorrect.

Comment: why don't you want to use the razor syntax?

Comment: You are already using razor syntax with `@Url.Action("AssignTemplate", "TemplateMapper")`. Furthermore, your input should be of type `submit` instead of `button`, without any function call for the `onclick` event. And your ActionResult should return a View

Comment: @chiapa: Well yes, besides that. What I mean is that I want to avoid Html.BeginForm and other simillar helpers.

Comment: Well, you don't have to use them, they are optional. For example, in the code you posted, you are using a regular HTML form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently using Razor syntax all over:

- @Url.Action("AssignTemplate", "TemplateMapper")
- @foreach (KeyValuePair entry in Model.templates)
- @entry.Key

But here's what you should do:

**View:**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="../TemplateMapper/AssignTemplate" method="post">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Template:</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select id="template" name="myDropDownList">
                @foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> entry in Model.templates)
                {
                    <option value="@entry.Key">@entry.Value</option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Assign" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult AssignTemplate(string myDropDownList)
{
     return View();
}
```

Assuming you have a View named `AssignTemplate`

Comment: why do I need two parameters in the controller to access one value from the droplist?

Answer (score 2):

The button that you're using to submit will perform an HTTP GET on your controller method, as it is changing the document url on click.

Your controller method is restricted to HTTP POST by the [HttpPost] attribute, hence the 404.

What you need to do is use an input of type "submit", which will post back the form to the action specified in the form tag, like so:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Assign"  />
```

This is the easy and appropriate way to submit form data to the server.

Additionally, you will need to assign a name to the select element to ensure that it's value gets bound to the parameter on your controller method

```
<select id="template" name="templateId">
```

Comment: How does this translate into the controller?

Comment: The name of the select element is used to build up the form submission, and your controller method has a similarly named parameter, so the MVC model binder can assign the selected value to your parameter.