# mvc pass values from inputs to action with model

Tags: c#, post, model-view-controller

my problem is the following.

I have a list page where i have a list of all my current user accounts, showing email firstname and lastname. So basically i want to 3 input fields in the first row of the table so i can add a filter method when i press a button.

[Currently looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwlBB.png)

```
public class UserListModel 
    {  

        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public List<UserAccount> UserAccounts { get; set; }
```

I've created this model particularly for the fitler function but how do i know pass the values from the input fields into a controller action via the model?

```
<td>
                <input class="input-sm" type="text" id="mail" name="email" value="" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="input-sm" type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" value="" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="input-sm" type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" value="" />
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Filter", "Filter",null, new { @class = "btn btn-info btn-large" })

            </td>
```

I've tried it with an action Link and Post but it didnt work

This is the method in my controller, currently does not filter anything just prints out the list again, how can i now access those values in this action?

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Filter(UserListModel model)
        {


            return View("List", userAccountService.GetUserAccounts());
        }
```

Comment: I don't see you pass anything to `GetUserAccounts()` so whatever that does, I don't see how it could know how or if you want to filter.

Comment: The GetUserAccounts doesnt fitler anything it just gets all the database entries and puts it into a list. Which works perfectly fine, the filter method deosnt filter anything at all yet since im still trying to get the values avilable in the filter method

Comment: So back to my original comment that I deleted. What doesn't work? Is `model` null? Does it help if you correct the capitalization of the html input `name`s?

Comment: I've changed the capitalization and yes my issue is that the model in the filter action is just null

Comment: Where is your form code in the view? Don't mix your models, you should have your view model and post model separate. Have a look at this answer to help you understand form submission: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28050493/submit-form-in-mvc-using-html